# JMS vs Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle-aq

My project connects to a database using hibernate, getting connections from a connection pool on JBoss. I want to replace some of the reads/writes to tables with publish/consume from queues. I built a working example that uses OracleAQ, however, I am connecting to the DB using:

`AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory` followed by `createQueueConnection`,
then using `createQueueSession` to get a (JMS) `QueueSession` on which I can call `createProducer` and `createConsumer`.

So I know how to do what I want using a `jms.QueueSession`. But using hibernate, I get a `hibernate.session`, which doesn't have those methods.

I don't want to open a new connection every time I perform an action on a queue - which is what I am doing now in my working example. Is there a way to perform queue operations from a `hibernate.session`? Only with SQL queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing a JMS (message queue) session with a Hibernate (database) session. The Hibernate framework doesn't have any overlap with JMS, so it can't be used to do both things.

You'll need 2 different sessions for this to work:

1. A Hibernate Session (`org.hibernate.Session`) for DB work
2. A JMS Session (`javax.jms.Session`) to to JMS/queue work

Depending on your use case, you may also want an XA transaction manager to do a proper two-phase commit across both sessions and maintain transactional integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for some "sane" way how to use JMS connection to manipulate database data. There is not any. Dean is right, you have to use two different connections to the same data and have distributed XA transaction between them.

This solution opens a world of various problems never seen before. In real life distributed transactions can really be non-trivial. Surprisingly in some situations Oracle can detect that two connections are pointing into the same database and then two-phase commit can be bypassed - even when using XA.